# after using react-navigation-redux, get the warning

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

version:

`"dependencies": {
"prop-types": "^15.6.1",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.2",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
"react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^1.0.5",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
},`

After using the latest version of `react-navigation` with `redux`, i get the message:

> **'Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.'**
>   I didn't use *isMounted* in my code.

I don't know why this happen. 
I haven't get this message before.

Need some help, please.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {handleNav} from '../../actions/navAction';
import styles from '../styles/styles';
const Login = ({handleNav}) => (
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text>Login Page</Text>
<Text>Login Page</Text>
<Text>Login Page</Text>
<Text>Login Page</Text>
<Text>Login Page</Text>
<Text>Login Page</Text>
<Button
title = {'Login Button'}
onPress = {handleNav.bind(null, 'MAIN')}
/>
<Button
title={'go to register page'}
onPress={handleNav.bind(null, 'REGISTER')}
/>
</View>
);
Login.propTypes = {
handleNav:PropTypes.func,
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({handleNav},dispatch);
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `redux navigation setup`, and also how you're handling the `react navigation listener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, its react-navigation issue (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3956),

still the next release, you can solve the issue using below:

> import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
>
> YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated']);

Comment: Thx any way. The buddy who give the temporary solution in  (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3956) is me.

Answer (score 1):

Library that you use have this dependency. 
try update deprecated packages :
npm outdated  - (will show you all packages that can be updated)

if all  packages updated : Wait for new version or go back to :
  "react": "16.3.0-rc.0",
  "react-native": "0.54.3",

Comment: I found the same problem in github, I think it is bug.https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3956.